# Bounty uses association bonus or gained rep first?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, protected-questions, association

**Read here first:** [Why can't I post an answer to a question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/why-cant-i-post-an-answer-to-a-question)

According to LessPop_MoreFizz, I would need to earn 10 rep *on the site* in order to answer the protected question.  So I got 13 rep and went back to the protected question.
**Guess what? I still can't answer it!**

A possible issue could be the fact that I started a bounty in during my rep hunting.  The thing I'm confused about is whether a bounty takes your association bonus first, or your *gained* rep first?

Comment: Yeah, it can't possibly cover all the corners. "Need to have at least 10 reputation points, minus association bonus" or something like that would be more clear, but too long.