# Unable to answer a protected question

Tags: bug, reputation, bounties, protected-questions

I recently came across a protected question on Android Enthusiasts([Profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/27149/lucky?tab=reputation))

[How can I install APK file on Bluestacks app player?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42983/how-can-i-install-apk-file-on-bluestacks-app-player)

and came to know that assosiated bonus reputations are not considered as actual reps to answer a protected question from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195468/unable-to-answer-a-protected-question-in-beta).

But I have already earned more than 10 points. I had 130+ reps few days back. I had 5 upvotes on a question, placed a bounty of 50 reps and I had 80+reps and got 10 points from one upvote of 5 answer, and edited 8 posts(16reps). But it just recognizes me as if I just scored 2 reps(100bonus + 2). So my total reps including the bonus is 152 and my current rep is 102(50 for bounty). But actually I already got more than 10 reps from doing all the above things. Is it that if once a bonus is rewarded it's not considered as reputation as trusted user. I'm confused with the concept, could anyone explain how this works?

So why can't I answer the protected question if I had already scored more than 10 reps?

Comment: Some further related reading: [A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238082/226203) [B](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238296/226203) [C](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498/226203) [D](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254184/226203)

Comment: @BillyMailman so that means even if if scored more than 10 reps..only the current score is considered and it should be 111 to answer questions..

Comment: The check is not very smart: if it detects association bonus was awarded, it's expecting you to have 110 points in order to answer protected questions. Simple as that. Bug or not bug? Only the dev team can tell. Might take 6-8 hours to get answer, or 6-8 years, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like the question hinges on whether your bounty came against "rep you earned on this site" or "association bonus." I am sure the code is easiest if you just say "this user has 102 rep, they have earned the association bonus, therefore they don't have enough rep to answer protected questions." Doing that effectively takes the bounty out of the rep you earned on this site.

Perhaps it would be better if the code looked a little deeper, but I suspect this is an edge case. Bountying yourself down to less than 111 rep doesn't happen very often.

Comment: The idea of protecting by having at least 10 points is to ensure that the user is familiar with the site. If user earned 50 points proves that user familiar with the site. Spending them on bounty should not be considered when determine eligibility for answering protected questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have earned 52 reps on the site and have used 50 reps to post a bounty. This makes you ineligible for the 'answering protected question' privilege. At this point you stand at less than 10 points (taking away the association bonus).

> Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count.

Ref: https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

To be able to answer a protected question is a privilege but currently you don't have that privilege because of the bounty you have posted.

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

Ref: https://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: yeah i know but my question is why 10 reps is again starting from the beginning..it should consider the points i had scored before..so once i crossed the 111 reps it should always allow me to answer protected questions..but its not how it works currently and if i look at my priveleges page it shows that i can answer protected questions but i can't do that right now and thats misleading..

Comment: @Lucky you currently have access to the 'Remove New User Restrictions' privilege which is correct. However if you look on the privilege page http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user, it says **one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count.** This is an added restriction for answering protected questions.

Comment: @Lucky regarding your question "my question is why 10 reps is again starting from the beginning..it should consider the points i had scored before..so once i crossed the 111 reps it should always allow me to answer protected questions". **No, this is not the way it works on Stack Exchange sites**. It is not a bug. It is by design.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: It is against the original design [Allow people to answer protected questions if they have earned at least some amount of combined SE rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129223)
The idea of protecting by having at least 10 points is to ensure that the user is familiar with the site. If user earned 50 points proves that user is familiar with the site rules. Spending them on bounty should not be considered when determine eligibility for answering protected questions.